# C# workaround to prevent FileStream from blocks files

Tags: c#

There's a known elegant solution to auto-delete files: open in a persistent FileStream with FileOptions.DeleteOnClose. Then a file could be used by other streams (with proper FileShare options).

However, Notepad or File.ReadAllText() fails to open the file (access exception).

Any idea for workaround ? (My efforts and googling have brought nothing but a headache.)

Comment: Are you using the file in process and wanting to access it while the file stream has it open? ```FileOptions.Asynchronous``` might be what you're referring to.  Apologies if I'm confused on the question.

Comment: I've tried this option as well but with no success :(

Comment: Where is the file located?  Have you tried elevating the privileges?

Comment: You should set the access safety in the Opener stream, something like `OpenerStream.SetAccessControl([FileSecurity])` with `AccessControlSections.All`. Then use the opener stream SafeFileHandle as the file handle of other streams: `FileStream Writer new FileStream(OpenerStream.SafeFileHandle, FileAccess.ReadWrite);`. The point is, if you open the file with `FileOptions.DeleteOnClose`, any stream that acces that file, when closed/disposed, will delete it.

Comment: 1) Thx for your idea - will test SetAccessControl tomorrow (i want to "unlock" the file for Notepad, not stream). There's no problem when only Streams are used.

2) Nope - the file will be deleted only after all FileStreams close it.

Comment: @Michael Puckett II, the file is in subfolder inside %temp% but it doesn't matter.